# Improving Newton Iteration

Tags: optimization

I am a problem a to determine a minimum of a function by a method using the iterative gradient methods and Newton.
Whether à function of type $f(x,y)=100\cdot(y-x^{2})^{2} + (1-x)^{2}$ how I can to determine with the methods of gradient and newton ?

Thanks guys

Comment: This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Answer (score 0):

I found this on Wikipedia and I tried to do a draft on paper:

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fu9cw.jpg)